# Swift language and swift property wrapper, what's the use of `nonmutating set`?

Tags: swift, swiftui, property-wrapper

In SwiftUI, @State is defined as:

```swift
@frozen @propertyWrapper public struct State<Value> : DynamicProperty {
```

And it has a computed property:

```swift
    public var wrappedValue: Value { get nonmutating set }
```

Question:

1. why doesn't `wrappedValue` need to implement the getter and setter? what is this shorthand syntax?
2. what's the intention of `nonmutating set`? is it trying to disable the setter?
3. questions around the `nonmutating set` is sometimes mutating in the following snippet:

```swift
struct PlayButtonStackOverflow: View {
    @State private var isPlaying: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        // TODO: 3.3: this does NOT change the state. why?
        $isPlaying.wrappedValue = true
        print($isPlaying.wrappedValue.description) // prints false
        
        return Button(isPlaying ? "isPlaying = true" : "isPlaying = false") {
        // TODO: 3.1: this does change the state.
            $isPlaying.wrappedValue = true
            // TODO: 3.1: and this prints true, why?
            print($isPlaying.wrappedValue )
            // `$isPlaying.wrappedValue` is accessing the State.projectValue, which is a Binding, and the Binding.wrappedValue has a non mutating setter. how come setter is actually mutating?

            // TODO: 3.2: Compile error: Referencing property 'wrappedValue' requires wrapper 'Binding<Bool>'
            // why? is there a way to access the State.wrappedValue setter? How is it being disabled?
            // isPlaying.wrappedValue = true
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

**Update A:**

Line at `TODO 3.3` gives `Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.` That explains some part of it. Since a state change triggers the body to evaluate again. But in this case, all mutation is in one direction.

Question A.1: why is `TODO 3.3` still prints false?

Question A.2: trying to wrap my head around this, is `$isPlaying.wrappedValue = true` and `isPlaying = true` having the same effect at line `TODO 3.3`?

**Question A.3**: since Binding is a struct, passing a value type around create copies of it. But in this case passing around `$isPlaying` to another func can mutate some value at call site? why?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/wrappedvalue

Comment: SwiftUI puts the value of a `State` in a secret storage. `State` doesn't hold the value so there isn't anything to mutate. `DynamicProperty` (where the `wrappedValue` is declared) is a bridge to the storage.

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions in one post. Edit your question so that it only asks one question.

Comment: Also `$isPlaying.wrappedValue = true` is unnecessary. You can just use `isPlaying = true`

Comment: @Sweeper it is essentially one question about how property wrappers work

Comment: @malhal Multiple questions or not, this is still too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Sweeper is your main concern here too many questions or questions too broad? I'm trying to strike a balance. I see that q1, q2 asking "how does property wrapper work?" can be viewed as too broad. But then q3 in the code snippet is very specific. (specific, but naturally there're many of them.) Section A is to provide more context to connect them. I feel the answer to all these should be a wholistic one but I struggle to get the question appear as tight without seeing the answer first.

Answer (score 1):

1. thats the public declaration, the implementation is private and hidden.
2. it's because the setter isn't changing the value of that struct, the setter is just forwarding the call on to an internal object.
3. You need to call the `isPlaying` state getter somewhere in `body` for the set to be detected and `body` to be called again. SwiftUI tracks these dependencies. `let _ = isPlaying` at the top of `body` would do it.

It might help to mention the `$` syntax is sugar for `Binding(get: { }, set: { })` i.e. a pair of 2 closures. Declaring `$isPlaying`, i.e. `Binding(get: { self.isPlaying }, set { self.isPlaying - newValue})` does not call the `@State var isPlaying` getter immediately so is not tracked as a dependency on `body`.

Property wrappers also have an [`mutating func update()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty), which SwiftUI calls before calling `body`, docs say "SwiftUI calls this function before rendering a view’s body to ensure the view has the most recent value.". It's possible that this gets the value back out of the internal object and sets it on this struct.